# How to change the attribute set of the product via programatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.2, attribute-set

I have created custom attributes for the attribute sets namely **set1 and set2.**

I have created the products via script with attribute set name as set1.
The products are saved successfully.

But Now I wish to change the attributeset name from set1 to set2.

Please provide me a solution **how do i update the attribute set for the existing products while saving the product via programatically.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$attributeSetId = 12; //you can change as per your requirement.
$product_id = 10;
$storeId = YOUR STORE ID;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$product->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId)->setStoreId($storeId)->save();
```

Comment: I have done this for configurable product but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Product Factory and save with Resource Model.
In the example below, the $productData argument contains the main product data. This data came from the product collection.
I walked through the collection with the iterator `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator::walk` and used as a callback a method similar to `changeAttributeSet($productData,$newAttributeSetId)`.
I changed some points to make the example simpler.

```php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory */
private $productFactory;

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product */
private $productResourceModel;

...

public function changeAttributeSet($productData,$newAttributeSetId)
{
    $product = $this->productFactory->create();
    $product->setData($productData);
    $product->setData('attribute_set_id',$newAttributeSetId);
    try {
        $this->productResourceModel->save($product);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$productRepository = $objectManager->get(ProductRepositoryInterface::class);
$attributeSetRepository = $objectManager->get(AttributeSetRepositoryInterface::class);

// Load the product by ID
$productId = 1; // Replace with your product ID
$product = $productRepository->getById($productId);

// Set the new attribute set name
$newAttributeSetName = 'set2'; // Replace with your new attribute set name

// Get the new attribute set ID
$attributeSet = $attributeSetRepository->get($newAttributeSetName);
$newAttributeSetId = $attributeSet->getAttributeSetId();

// Update the product's attribute set ID
$product->setAttributeSetId($newAttributeSetId);

// Save the product
$productRepository->save($product);

echo "Product attribute set updated successfully.\n";
```

Make sure to replace 1 with the actual ID of your product and 'set2' with the name of the new attribute set.